# Add column to date time indexed Dataframe from regular data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes of the same length (39014 rows), one has datetime as its index, and the other one just a regular index. I need to copy one column into the other one but when the copy is being made it returns `Nans`. I did:

```
df_datetime["newcol"]=df_regular["col"]
```

If you check the column `newcol` in `df_datetime` it's a column full of `Nan`, even though the column `col` of `df_regular` has numbers. Why is this happening? How can I fix it? Thanks!

Also tried

```
pd.merge(df_datetime, df_regular[["col"]], left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
```

And the same happens

Comment: Please include a sample of `df_regular` and `df_datetime`

Comment: pandas does "intrinsic data alignment" means that most of all operations in pandas are done with respect to the index and column headers matching.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the indices are not aligned.

When you assign a new column like that, `df_datetime.loc[x, 'newcol']` will have the same value as `df_regular.loc[x, 'newcol']`

You need to replace the index of `df_datetime` with a datetime index.

Answer (score 0):

What if you do this:

```
listOfColumn = list(df_regular["col"])
df_datetime["newcol"] = listOfColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

As *df_datetime* and *df_regular* I prepared the following DataFrames:

```
             N1
Dat            
2019-09-01  120
2019-09-02  130
2019-09-03  140
2019-09-04  150
2019-09-05  160
```

and

```
   col  N2
0   23  19
1   26  32
2   48  61
3   51  53
4   62  60
```

Both with 5 rows.

If you want to "add" *col* column from *df_regular* to *df_datetime*
ignoring index values in both DataFrames, run:

```
df_datetime['newcol'] = df_regular.col.values
```

The result is:

```
             N1  newcol
Dat                    
2019-09-01  120      23
2019-09-02  130      26
2019-09-03  140      48
2019-09-04  150      51
2019-09-05  160      62
```